# How to select elements of a specific type in a list?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function to select only the elements of `my_list` that are of the type specified by `type_elem`. Here is my code:

```
def filter_list(my_list, type_elem):
    for elem in my_list:
        if type_elem == int and isinstance(elem, str):
            my_list.remove(elem)
    return my_list


print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], int))
```

In this case output must be: `[35, 10]`
If it were str, for example, as a second argument, the output must be `['abc']`. And so on

Comment: Note the edits I made to your title and your question. These come directly from [ask], which describes what your question should contain. Please [edit] your question to explain the _problem_ you are facing with your code. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, you don't actually care what `type_elem` is: you only care about whether an element of the list is an instance of `type_elem`. This can be checked by simply doing `if isinstance(elem, type_elem)`.

Also, you should create a new list to which you *add* the elements you want, instead of removing from the one you are iterating over, since that can lead to problems.

Your function would become:

```
def filter_list(my_list, type_elem):
    result = []
    for elem in my_list:
        if isinstance(elem, type_elem):
            result.append(elem)

    return result
```

Since you're just building up the `result` list in that loop, it can be replaced by a list comprehension:

```
def filter_list(my_list, type_elem):
    return [elem for elem in my_list if isinstance(elem, type_elem)]
```

Now, calling the function with different `type_elem` returns a list containing only the elements of that type:

```
>>> print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], int))
[35, True, 10]

>>> print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], str))
['abc']

>>> print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], bool))
[True]
```

Note that the boolean is returned when you ask for ints because a boolean is a special case of integers. To prevent this, we could change the `isinstance(elem, type_elem)` to `type(elem) == type_elem`, which checks that the types are equal and doesn't evaluate to `True` for derived classes (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549854/843953):

```
def filter_list(my_list, type_elem):
    return [elem for elem in my_list if type(elem) == type_elem]
```

Now, we get the expected output:

```
>>> print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], int))
[35, 10]

>>> print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], str))
['abc']

>>> print(filter_list([35, True, 'abc', 10], bool))
[True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is you only remove elements if type_elem == int, so it will work for int but not for other types. Try this:

```
def filter_list(my_list, type_elem): 
    return [e for e in my_list if isinstance(e, type_elem)]
```

Take into account that bool type is also an integer type